# count total, total nulls, mean and median

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let us say I have a data frame with a column called values, and for this column, I want to calculate the total observations, total null observations, mean and median values per group.

I.e.,

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'date_ym':['2018-01', '2018-01','2018-01','2018-01','2018-02','2018-02','2018-03'],'category':['A','A','A','B','A','B','B'], 'values':[np.nan,4.0,5.1,np.nan,6.2,np.nan,np.nan]})
mydf
Out[134]: 
  category  date_ym  values
0        A  2018-01     NaN
1        A  2018-01     4.0
2        A  2018-01     5.1
3        B  2018-01     NaN
4        A  2018-02     6.2
5        B  2018-02     NaN
6        B  2018-03     NaN
```

If I use groupby and agg, I get the following output:

```
mydf.groupby(['date_ym','category']).agg(['count', 'mean', 'median']).reset_index()
Out[135]: 
   date_ym category values             
                     count  mean median
0  2018-01        A      2  4.55   4.55
1  2018-01        B      0   NaN    NaN
2  2018-02        A      1  6.20   6.20
3  2018-02        B      0   NaN    NaN
4  2018-03        B      0   NaN    NaN
```

But the output I'd really want is as follows:

```
   date_ym category values             
                     count  countNAs mean median
0  2018-01        A      2  1        4.55   4.55
1  2018-01        B      0  1        NaN    NaN
2  2018-02        A      1  0        6.20   6.20
3  2018-02        B      0  1        NaN    NaN
4  2018-03        B      0  1        NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using

```
def countNAs(x): return x.isnull().sum()
mydf.groupby(['date_ym','category']).agg(['count',countNAs, 'mean', 'median']).reset_index()
Out[647]: 
   date_ym category values                      
                     count countNAs  mean median
0  2018-01        A      2      1.0  4.55   4.55
1  2018-01        B      0      1.0   NaN    NaN
2  2018-02        A      1      0.0  6.20   6.20
3  2018-02        B      0      1.0   NaN    NaN
4  2018-03        B      0      1.0   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to use an ordinary function rather than to create an anonymous function using a lambda, then immediately bind it to a name, and then use a dunder attribute to put the name back in there?  What's wrong with `def countNAs(x): return x.isnull().sum()`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a straight-forward approach but it does the job.

```
#aggregate on size which counts NA's
mydf = mydf.groupby(['date_ym','category']).agg(['size', 'count', 'mean', 'median']).reset_index()
#Renaming columns
mydf.columns = ['date_ym','category', 'countNA', 'count', 'mean', 'median']
#countNA = size - count
mydf['countNA'] = mydf['countNA'] - mydf['count']
```